# Diagonal matrices and integrals

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $$A=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(B,x)\ dx,$$ where $B$ is a $3\times3$ matrix. The result I'm looking for is that if $B$ is diagonalized with an orthogonal matrix, then is A diagonalized by the SAME matrix? For example, we could take $$f(B,x)=\frac{1}{B+xI}.$$

Comment: What is the meaning of $\sqrt{B+x}$ ?

Comment: My guess is that the answer depends much on the function $f$. When $f$ is defined so as it can be expressed as a power series in $B$ (like in this case), then surely yes.

Comment: Oops, I didn't finish the bottom correctly. I fixed it.

Comment: If it's $\det$, then $A$ is just a number. What do you mean by "diagonalize"?

Comment: Sorry, let me try to get a better example. Say it is $\frac{1}{B+xI}$

Comment: Please refer to my first comment. Yes in this case. No in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The holomorphic functional calculus preserves diagonal matrices, and preserves similarity transformations.  That is, if $f$ is  analytic in a neighbourhood of the eigenvalues of a matrix $B$, then

1. if $B$ is diagonal, then so is $f(B)$.
2. $f(SBS^{-1}) = S f(B) S^{-1}$.